# Creating array from two variable function with one variable being an array

Tags: python, arrays, list, function, variables

As I did in cases zArr and rzArr I want to use function dl(z) to create an array or list dlArr that contains the generated values from dl given z from zArr and rz from rzArr. I tried doing it like this but the syntax is wrong:

```
dlArr= [(dl(z,rz) for z in zArr & rz in rzArr)]
```

Relating code for reference:

```
zArr = np.linspace(0.01, 2.0, 1048)

def dist_integrand(z):
   dist_integrand = 1.0 / np.sqrt(Omegam * (1 + z) ** 3 + Omegal)
   return dist_integrand

def rz(z):
   rz = integrate.quad(dist_integrand, 0, z)
   return rz

rzArr = (rz(z) for z in zArr)

def dl(z,rz):
    dl = (1+z) * rz
    return dl

#!!
dlArr= [(dl(z,rz) for z in zArr & rz in rzArr)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to iterate over a zipped pair of arrays:

```
... for z, rz in zip(zArr, rzArr)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

The `zip( ... )` call is generating a sequence of tuples,
and then a tuple unpack operation binds
the `z, rz` names to each generated value.

---

To better see the details of what's going on, try this:

```
from pprint import pp

pp(list(zip(zArr, rzArr)))
```

Comment: `arr1 & arr2` would be an interesting syntactic sugar for `zip()` though...

Comment: It already has a meaning: take the bitwise AND of the two arguments.

Comment: Not for lists / sequences though.  Ditto how bitwise OR was added for dict merging.  Not saying it's a *good* idea, just an interesting one from the OP :)